# Table Within Div Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

So I am web developer who used to have a kind graphics design person help me out on this sort of browser compatibility hell, but alas he has moved on to greener pastures. The following html looks fine and dandy on chrome, but the table I am using to align my form is sleeping on the job on the bottom in ie and firefox. Should I never use tables? Is the float in the div tags screwing everything up? Any hints or suggestions for improving my html and css would be much appreciated.

Also, the text area text gets a little screwy sometimes in terms of where it is positioned in the box.

Thank you all.

```
<div style="border-style:solid; border-color:#336699; padding: 5px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:600px; height:300px;" id="demoContainer">

    <div style="" id="demo">
        <div style="" id="demoHeader">
            <img src="someimage" />
            <span style="font-size:32px;">Demo</span>
        </div>
        <div style="" id="demoBody">
            <form method="get">
                <div style="float:left; padding:5px;" id="demoBodyText">
                    <textarea style="resize:none;" rows="10" cols="30">
                        Enter demo text here...
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right; padding:5px;" id="demoBodyOptions">
                    <table style="float:right;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Option 1:
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <select style="">
                                    <option>asdf</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Option 2:
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <select style="align:left;">
                                    <option value="320">Fastest</option>
                                    <option value="260">Faster</option>
                                    <option value="200">Fast</option>
                                    <option value="170" selected="selected">Default</option>
                                    <option value="130">Slow</option>
                                    <option value="110">Slower</option>
                                    <option value="80">Slowest</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Option 3:
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <select>
                                    <option value="4.2">Highest</option>
                                    <option value="3">Higher</option>
                                    <option value="2">High</option>

                                    <option value="1" selected>Default</option>
                                    <option value="0.8">Low</option>
                                    <option value="0.6">Lower</option>
                                    <option value="0.4">Lowest</option>
                                </select style="align:left;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Option 4
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <select>
                                    <option value="none">None</option>

                                </select style="align:left;"    >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>  
            </form>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;" id="demoFooter">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Added image in how it displays in my firefox version 10.

[image]

Comment: What IE version are you testing with?

As for the `textarea` text, `textarea` interprets spaces literally, so you should have this instead: `<textarea style="resize:none;" rows="10" cols="30">Enter demo text here...</textarea>`

Comment: IE 9 actually. The table within the div just caused the table to float way off to nowhere. Also, if you do not mind answering what I am working on right now, is trying to get that Demo text in the header aligned with the image. I miss my web designer buddy :'(

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to see a difference between IE8 and FF/chrome, but I might be blind.. http://jsfiddle.net/E7gms/ does this still look screwy in IE?

Comment: There are some slight differences, but we're missing the main CSS file which I assume my contain more layout information. Could you post a jsfiddle with the source and relevant CSS classes?

Comment: No everything is inline css because we have partners that use our demos and we do not want their style sheets to get rid of my company's logo the link that will eventually go in footer, nor the coloring.

Comment: ALso, added a screen shot of what i looks like in my firefox. It looks very similar in IE.

Comment: See my answer and let me know if any issues.. by understanding you problem i create the fiddle and check the code in diff browsers.. Please let me know if i am lagging some where..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the fiddle - Is this you are looking for?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jKtkq/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jKtkq/embedded/result/

Screen shot: http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/7676/tableissue.jpg

Comment: Yeppers, the width of the two inner div's text and options was too great compared to the constraint of the outermost div element.

Comment: Could you tell, what you changed?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `float:right` **after** a `float:left` this seems pretty normal.

Try to switch the order of the two or give the second one also `float:left`

Or maybe the padding is the problem?
http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/55cXT/
What are the `width` of your floated divs `#demoBodyText`  and `#demoBodyOptions`?